# Unable to transform Presentation object from python-pptx library to upload to MS Graph API service endpoint

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, python-pptx

**Context**

I have a python script that uses the openpyxl and python-pptx libraries to generate Workbooks and PowerPoints respectively.  These files need to be uploaded via the Microsoft Graph API as an octet-stream directly from virtual memory.

**Obstacle**

All works well for the Workbook thanks to the `save_virtual_workbook` method, which returns an in-memory workbook; but there is no analogous method like `save_virtual_presentation` that I know of, so it has been a challenge to get the Presentation object in a form that can be streamed via the `io.BytesIO.read()` method.

The python.pptx [documentation](http://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/presentation.html#pptx.presentation.Presentation.save) says that `Presentation.save(file)` works...

> "where `file` can be either a path to a file (a string) or a file-like
>   object."

Except while performing POC, I don't have the option of saving to the local file system, so I've experimented with various approaches with a file-like object.  None come close to being accepted in the put request to the MS Graph API endpoint, except for the attempt below.

**Nearest Miss**

In this case, `prs` is the Presentation object that is created in previous code, which I have not included here on account of it being 556 lines.

```
<<Omitted code that generates the Workbook and PowerPoint, of which prs is an output>>

headers = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer {0}'.format(access_token),
           'Accept' : 'application/json',
           'Content-Type' : 'application/octet-stream'}

endpoint_url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/<<removed id>>:/Test.pptx:/content'

target_stream = io.BytesIO()
prs.save(target_stream)

response = requests.put(url=endpoint_url,
                        headers=headers,
                        data=io.BytesIO.read(target_stream),
                        verify=False,
                        params=None)
```

The put request succeeds, BUT the file saved to the service endpoint is an empty pptx shell.  I've ruled out that `prs` itself is an empty pptx shell, so I conclude that `target_stream` is not a valid transformation of `prs`.

**Summary**

Can someone please help me by suggesting how to transform the Presentation object `prs` into something that I can plug into `data=io.BytesIO.read(<<input>>)` and successfully upload to the MS Graph API endpoint?   I would be much obliged!

Comment: What's wrong with using `data=target_stream.get_value()`? There shouldn't be any need for an external function, if io.BytesIO.read even is that (haven't heard of it and can't find it in docs). If what you're getting is an empty presentation consistent with the starting `python-pptx` "template" presentation, I'd suspect your presentation generation code, like opening a new prs at the end or something. Maybe you should show at least a minimum amount of that to write one simple slide or something.

Comment: `getvalue()` without the underscore did the trick.  A thousand thanks, @scanny!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks ok, up until you read the `BytesIO` object. In the `put()` call, try using `data=target_stream.getvalue()` instead of the `read()` call you have there now. That's the conventional way to get the contents of a `BytesIO` or `StringIO` object as bytes.